# Database is [nothing but] an organized form of data

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, pronouns

I encountered a sentence

> Database is **nothing but** an organized form of data [...].

and got confused by the part *"nothing but"*.

1. What is it used for and what meaning does it convey here?
2. How correct is it to start a formal definition with "nothing but"?
3. How is it different from the next quote?

> Database is an organized form of data [...].

I've seen a few sentences with this structure before. They were pretty logical, rather informal, and, I guess, *"nothing but"* meant *"only"* there.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the original sentence start *"**A** database is ..."*?  Otherwise it's not grammatical.

Comment: @Andrew "A" wasn't there.

Comment: Ok, just be aware then that's not correct English.   Also, it's a bit wordy -- I would just say, *"A database is nothing but **organized data**"* or even *"A database is nothing but **data, organized**"* if I wanted to be more dramatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**nothing but** means a little more than "only".

Compare:

> He's nothing but a scoundrel.

That could be paraphrased, "He has no virtues. He is is a scoundrel, plain and simple."

It reduces something to its *essence* (in the eyes of the speaker).

It can be used with hyperbole:

> He bought a used car and it turned out to be nothing but a heap of rusty nuts and bolts.

So, to say that a database is "nothing but an organized form of data" ignores what are (in the speaker's eyes) irrelevant details, such as fault-tolerance, atomicity, adherence to standards, and so forth. The speaker is making a *reductive* assertion.

Answer (score 2):

As [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nothing-but) notes:

> ***You use nothing but*** in front of a noun, an infinitive without 'to', or an '-ing' form ***to mean 'only'.***

“Nothing but” is an expression   used to emphasise the concept that the subject in question is characterized by one specific aspect.

It is often used also in book titles, see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nothing%20but%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)